# How to allow users to add scripts like fb pixel code, analytics tracking code, custom scripts ,... and secure the platform from attks

Tags: php, security, xss, script-tag

I'm working in a platform that creating websites some thing like wix.
So each one of our users can own it's own internal webpage.
I need to allow them to add scripts to there internal webpages; Google analytics tracking code, facebook pixel code, or any custom widgets.
So I may accept these scripts via textarea and save it in the db, then add it in the user webpage header

But, what about security, some thing like XSS attack
Is there any ideas to accept custom scripts and prevent users from attacking the platform?

Note: I don't know much about how XSS and what it may do, I just need to secure the whole platform from attacks that may comes from the users (the internal webpages owners)

Comment: If you're permitting "any custom widgets" you've already abdicated responsibility for this. Your users can, and *will*, cause XSS vulnerabilities on the sites they control.

Comment: so, any ideas?
wix, instapages, lander, and all other site builders accepting custom scripts
how they are protecting the platform from such attacks?

Comment: Who said they do? You can put bad code on your Wix site. They protect their platform - those custom scripts are never going to be executed in the Wix admin. It's up to you to protect your Wix *site*. (That said, I'm sure they do some after-the-fact blacklisting of malicious scripts, and may run a WAF to look for things like attempts at SQL injection.)

Comment: As evidence: https://support.wix.com/en/article/embedding-custom-code-to-your-site "Wix does not provide support for technical difficulties associated with third-party code snippets."

Comment: I don't know much about XSS, and how it may used. So you mean if I print the script only in the user internal webpage, the main platform is still secured, nothing may happened to it? and if any attacking scripts it will only affect this webpage, and no chance to get some thing like other users sessions/cookies or get heigher level access or any similar attaks?

Comment: "I don't know much about XSS, and how it may used." If you're developing a platform, I'd start here. Learn what XSS is, how it can be used, how it can be combatted, etc.

Comment: Yes I read many articles, but I'm still not an expert in this field, it appears that there is no chance to attk the server, or the main platform, all possible damadge may affect the sub webpage and/or its visitors, am I right?